# Bivariate probability distributions with constraints

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two types of items $X$ and $Y$. I suppose the total number of items, given as the sum of the number of items of type $X$ and number of items of type $Y$,  $n_X+n_Y = N$ is fixed, and the number of items of type $X$ ($n_X$) is poisson distributed, namely:

$$P(n_x) = \frac{\exp(-x)x^{n_x}}{n_x!}$$

Is it possible to write the $P(n_y)$ and $P(n_y,n_x)$. I naively thought that since $n_x$ is Poisson distributed with mean $x$ then $P(n_y) = N-P(n_x)$ and $P(n_y,n_x) = P(n_x)(N-P(n_x))$ but clearly these don't normalise to 1.

In fact would it be possible to do this for any arbitrary distribution? How would $E[X^nY^m]$ be affected?

Answer (score 1):

The problem itself does not make much sense. X cannot be Poisson distributed as $X \leq N$ and we know the Poisson distribution can take on any natural number.

Comment: ok maybe that was a bad example, but say any arbitrayr probability distribution $P(n_x)$

Comment: Then $P(n_y) = 1 - P(n_x)$ and $P(n_y, n_x) = P(n_y | n_x)P(n_x) = P(n_x)$. Once $X$ is known, $Y$ is known.

Comment: @Zachary J. McNulty The first statement is not correct, if you sum both sides over the sample space you get N=0

Comment: You're right it should be $P_Y(n_y) = P_X(N - n_x)$

Comment: Just a quick question about your notation, what are you denoting with $P_Y(n_y)$ (what does the subscript Y on the P indicate?

Comment: P_Y(n_y) = Prob(Y = n_y)